How to minimise risks of a publicly accessible Azure SQL database?
What techniques can be used to protect an Azure database that's publicly accessible?
Due to the architecture of a legacy application I have to work with (which connects directly to an SQL instance using SQL login), I cannot restrict connections by IP (the users are in multiple locations on DHCP-based internet connections, so no way of knowing what IP they will be on), so have to allow all.
Additionally they are not AD authenticated, so cannot use AD/Entra auth.
This is clearly a risk, so what options do I have to minimise risk to the database?
Connections are encrypted, database instance is a random name and it has obscure usernames with strong passwords.
Jim

"I cannot restrict connections by IP, so have to allow all." - You forgot to say why that's so.

The users are in multiple locations on DHCP-based internet connections, so no way of knowing what IP they will be on.

Have you considered a VPN?

The best way to mitigate risks in that scenario is to use Always Encrypted. Azure by default encrypts data at rest with Transparent Data Encryption feature (it is turned on by default) and data in-transit in and out of Azure is always encrypted, but Always Encrypted adds encryption of data while in-use and not even the database engine can decrypt the data but the user application only.
In addition, you can set up Azure Advanced Threat Protection (ATP) which can help detect and respond to potential threats. It provides alerts for suspicious activities, such as SQL injection attacks, anomalous database access patterns, and potential vulnerabilities.
This tutorial can provide you detailed steps on securing the database, but for me Always Encrypted is your best option on that scenario. The Always Encrypted feature has some important limitations as explained on this official documentation.
